# Deserialize a SortedSet with a provided Comparator

Tags: jackson

Is it possible to deserialise a SortedSet or TreeSet (or SortedMap or TreeMap as a matter of fact) with a provided Comparator?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open Jackson issue ([jackson-databind#2162](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2162)) to allow specifying a `Comparator` when deserializing a `SortedMap`.  It has been open since October 2018, but it doesn't look like any work has been done on it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom [`Converter`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) which converts a `SortedSet` to one which is sorted using the desired `Comparator`:

```java
public static class MyStringSetConverter
        extends StdConverter<SortedSet<String>, SortedSet<String>> {
    private static final Comparator<String> COMPARATOR =
            String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

    @Override
    public SortedSet<String> convert(SortedSet<String> value) {
        SortedSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(COMPARATOR);
        sortedSet.addAll(value);
        return sortedSet;
    }
}
```

```java
public static class MyType {
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = MyStringSetConverter.class)
    private SortedSet<String> value;

    public SortedSet<String> getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(SortedSet<String> value) { this.value = value; }
    public String toString() { return Objects.toString(value); }
}
```